# Placing an if statement within a function?

Tags: python, function, if-statement

This is what I have so far:

```
def delivery(weight):
    if weight > 20:
        return delivery = 20
    if weight >= 20 and weight <= 50:
        return delivery = 20 + (weight)
    if weight > 50:
        return delivery = 10 + (1.2*weight)

delivery(30)

print(delivery)
```

I continue to get an incorrect outcome that says:

```
<function delivery at 0x7fb696c2fb90>
```

When I want my outcome to print 30. How can I fix this?

Comment: `delivery == 20` as a statement doesn't accomplish anything. Are you trying to `return` a value?

Comment: What [documentation](https://www.python.org/doc/) did you read on Python? Please cite it in your question.

Comment: i tried using return still get the same outcome @khelwood

Comment: learning it at university? unsure what you mean @BasileStarynkevitch

Comment: Look [here](https://docs.python.org/3/) and take several hours to read documentation. Study also for inspiration some existing open source projects on [github](https://github.com/) or [gitlab](https://gitlab.com/). Spend a few days *reading* things

Comment: still continue getting the same outcome @khelwood even with that ammendment

Comment: See [What is the purpose of a return statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129285/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-return-statement)

Comment: `weight <= 20 and weight >= 50` at the same time is impossible....

Comment: @ThierryLathuille changed still have the same outcome

Comment: Stack overflow is not a substitute for starting with basic tutorials.

Comment: This piece of code shows many misunderstandings. If your lessons don't help you more than this, I would really recommend that you find some friend or tutorial to learn the basics of the language.

Comment: Instead of `return delivery = 20 + (weight)` just do `return  20 + weight`

Answer (score 1):

I think you got confused between `=` and `==`, the first is an assignment (put right value into left), where the second is comparison, returning true or false depends if the two objects are equal or not.

The output you got is an output where you try to print a function.

Comment: Amended but still doesn't work

Answer (score -1):

```py
def delivery(weight):
  if (weight > 20):
    delivery = 20
  elif weight <= 20 and weight >= 50:
    delivery = 20 + (weight)
  elif weight > 50:
    delivery = 10 + (1.2*weight)
  return delivery


weight = 30

print(delivery(weight))
```

Use this code for what you expect....

Comment: This will print 20..

Comment: If `weight` is a number less than 20, this will collapse  telling you that delivery is not initiated.